# C memory leak even after free'ing pointer to struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, memory-leaks

I have a structure for the coefficients of a second degree polynome. I declare a variable of this structure type, I read the values of the coefficients, then I create and initialize a pointer to this structure. I then display the values of the coefficients, using my struct and my pointer to struct variables. Finally, I set my pointer to struct to NULL and I free it.

However, valgrind detects a memory leak and I cannot, for the life of me, understand why. Could you help me understand please?

```
valgrind ./polynome --leak-check=full 
==11046== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11046== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11046== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11046== Command: ./polynome --leak-check=full
==11046== 
2 3 4
pCoeff: a = 2.000000, b = 3.000000, c = 4.000000
 coeff: a = 2.000000, b = 3.000000, c = 4.000000
==11046== 
==11046== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11046==     in use at exit: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==11046==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 24 bytes allocated
==11046== 
==11046== LEAK SUMMARY:
==11046==    definitely lost: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==11046==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11046==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11046==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11046==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11046== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==11046== 
==11046== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11046== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Here is my C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
   double a;
   double b;
   double c;
} Coefficient;

int main() {
    Coefficient *pCoeff = NULL;
    Coefficient coeff;

    scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &coeff.a, &coeff.b, &coeff.c);

    pCoeff = (Coefficient *)malloc(sizeof(Coefficient));
    if (pCoeff == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation error.\n");
        exit(1);
    }   

    pCoeff = &coeff;

    printf("pCoeff: a = %lf, b = %lf, c = %lf\n", pCoeff->a, pCoeff->b, pCoeff->c);
    printf(" coeff: a = %lf, b = %lf, c = %lf\n", coeff.a, coeff.b, coeff.c);

    pCoeff = NULL; 
    free(pCoeff); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to free the pointer first. Then Set it to NULL.

Comment: @MartinZabel: if I don't set the pointer to NULL before free'ing, I get a double free or corruption error (because it still points to the adress of the coeff variable).

Comment: @user3121023: yes it does, I just wanted to test the equivalent of `int var = 3; int *p = &var;` in dynamic allocation using structures, and am baffled as to why I have a memory leak. Or do you mean to say that I am not supposed to do that?

Comment: I think that I should work with &coeff=NULL; free(pCoeff);

Comment: @user3121023: OK, thank you.

Comment: @ganchito55: No, it cannot work, as you cannot have the address operator at the left-hand part of an assignment.

Comment: @user3121023: Yes, that's right. The allocation is lost. Thanks, I understand now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Memory Leak 1

You first problem lies in the following statement, which does not correspond with what the code does:

> then I create and initialize a pointer to this structure

Remember that the variable `pCoeff` is a **pointer**, i.e. it stores an **address**.

In the line

> `pCoeff = (Coefficient *)malloc(sizeof(Coefficient));`

you store in `pCoeff` the **address** of the new dynamically allocated structure. Next, in the line

> `pCoeff = &coeff;`

you store in `pCoeff` (overwriting the previous value) the **address** of the statically allocated structure `coeff`. Doing so, you lose your only reference to the dynamically allocated memory, and thus cause a memory leak.

The correct solution to actually copy the **values** of the structure would be to either use the [`memcpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) function, or

```
*pCoeff = coeff;
```

## Memory Leak 2

The second problem lies in the order of statements during deallocation.

In the line

> ```
> pCoeff = NULL;
> ```

you store in `pCoeff` (overwriting the previous value) the NULL **address**. Doing so, you would again lose your only reference and cause a memory leak.

Then, in line

> ```
> free(pCoeff);
> ```

you call `free` with the value stored in `pCoeff`. Since the value is now `NULL`, the function doesn't do anything.

The correct deallocation sequence would have the two statements in reverse order:

```
pCoeff = NULL; 
free(pCoeff);
```

---

## Unnecessary Code

The variable `coeff` seems redundant, as you allocate the same type dynamically and copy the values. You could allocate first, and then read directly to the memory pointed by `pCoeff`.

For example:

```
Coefficient *pCoeff = NULL;
pCoeff = (Coefficient *)malloc(sizeof(Coefficient));
if (NULL == pCoeff) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation error.\n");
    exit(1);
}   

scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &pCoeff->a, &pCoeff->b, &pCoeff->c);
/* TODO: Check the return value of scanf. */

printf("pCoeff: a = %lf, b = %lf, c = %lf\n", pCoeff->a, pCoeff->b, pCoeff->c);

...
```

Comment: Thank you. It's clear now. Yes, `coeff` is redundant, I was just testing structures on the stack vs dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is these lines of code make no sense when taken together:

```
Coefficient *pCoeff = NULL;
Coefficient coeff;

// this points pCoeff at a malloc()'d structure
pCoeff = (Coefficient *)malloc(sizeof(Coefficient));

// this points pCoeff at the structure on the stack - and
// leaks the one malloc()`d above
pCoeff = &coeff;

pCoeff = NULL; 
// free() of a NULL pointer does nothing
free(pCoeff);
```

Either `malloc()` then `free()` a `Coefficient` structure, or use the one on the stack.  You don't need to do both.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it doesn't make sense. :) I was just trying to understand the underworkings of having structures on the stack vs using dynamic allocation. Thanks to your answer and the others I received, I now understand.